# JSF life cycle ends with validation

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `<p:commandButton action=#{bean.action} .../>`. The action method is not called. I  read [h:commandButton is not being invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked).
No 1-2 is checked, No 4-11 does not apply to my.
For No 3 I build a PhaseListener with an AfterPhase Method:

```
public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    System.out.println("after Phase: "+event.getPhaseId());
    FacesContext f= event.getFacesContext();
    List<FacesMessage> ml = f.getMessageList();
    for (FacesMessage m:ml){
        System.out.println(m.getSummary()+": "+m.getDetail());
    }
}
```

Which shows me that the cycle ends with PROCESS_VALIDATIONS(3) Phase but no messages. I restarted my servlet container in debug mode with a breakpoint set for caught and uncaught ValidatorExceptions (including its sub classes). But non is thrown.

Where can I look next?

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: With your actual code, we could only guess where's the real problem. It looks like some of your `UIInput` data is being converted/validated  and throwing some error. Try to post more of your JSF code and/or try commenting your `UIInput` components in your JSF page and then uncommenting one by one until find the problematic component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During minimization of the code to post a SSCCE (see comment above) I changed the `<p:commandButton>` to a `<h:commandButton>` which leads to a

`javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, 'someField' returned null`

because of a `<h:inputText value="#{someBean.someField.someOtherField}">` in the form. The PrimeFaces CommandButton does not render an error Message in this case.

Comment: Note that it's just been logged to the server log.